# Formatting of institution as author with natbib and numbered references

Tags: bibtex, natbib, elsarticle

I am editing a document to be submitted to an Elsevier journal. The Elsevier document class uses natbib to handle references. I am encountering a problem with the appearance of references that have an institution or organization as the author. For example, if the author is "US Department of Energy", I know I can force the output to appear as I've specified using double braces:

```
Author = {{US Department of Energy}}
```

The trouble I'm having is that while this achieves the desired effect, bibtex is treating the author name as a last name, so it gets formatted in the references list as:

> US Department of Energy, .

Using `\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}` gets rid of the comma, but there will still be a space between the end of the author and the period. Looking at the bbl file reveals that bibtex is adding `\xfnm[]` after the author name. If I remove this element in the author name in the bbl file, the extra comma and space go away. I know that the problem is created in part because of the bst file I'm using, but I'm not supposed to substitute another format. Is there anything I can do to prevent this extra element from being added to the bbl file by bibtex in the first place?

#### MWE: tex markup

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here I am going to use a reference with an institutional author~\cite{BTS2012}.

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{sources}

\end{document}
```

#### MWE: bibtex file (sources.bib)

```
@misc{BTS2012,
  Author= {{Bureau of Transportation Statistics}},
  Howpublished = {\url{http://www.bts.gov/programs/national_household_travel_survey/daily_travel.html}},
  Publisher = {{Department of Transportation}},
  Title = {{National Household Travel Survey: Daily Travel Quick Facts}},
  Year = {2012}}
```

Download [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdfislgtz6y894g/model3-num-names.bst) for model3-num-names.bst if needed.

#### New MWE (demonstrating author name double period formatting problem)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{BTS2012,
  Author= {{Bureau of Transportation Statistics}},
  Howpublished = {\url{http://www.bts.gov/programs/national_household_travel_survey/daily_travel.html}},
  Publisher = {{Department of Transportation}},
  Title = {{National Household Travel Survey: Daily Travel Quick Facts}},
  Year = {2012}}
@article{Shaw1985,
  Author = {Shaw, John J and Gendron, Robert F and Bertsekas, Dimitri P},
  Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems},
  Number = {2},
  Pages = {286--294},
  Title = {{Optimal Scheduling of Large Hydrothermal Power Systems}},
  Volume = {104},
  Year = {1985}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\begin{document}

Here's a reference with an institutional author~\cite{BTS2012}. Here's a journal reference~\cite{Shaw1985}. Notice how the periods terminating the authors' first and middle initials have been removed, and thus only a final period terminates the list of author names, rather than a terminating double period (which would appear as Bertsekas, D.P..).

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Download [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmsi0snia95nm9g/numcompress.sty) for the modified version of the numcompress package (see line 167).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first name is recorded in the `.bbl` file as an argument to the `\xfnm` command that's defined in the `thebibliography` environment only if it hasn't been defined before. So you can define it in your preamble in such a way that it does the usual thing when the argument is not empty, but nothing if it's empty.

In the example I added an (incomplete) entry just to show that the first name is picked up correctly. The `filecontents*` trick is just to make the example self contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{BTS2012,
  Author= {{Bureau of Transportation Statistics}},
  Howpublished = {\url{http://www.bts.gov/programs/national_household_travel_survey/daily_travel.html}},
  Publisher = {{Department of Transportation}},
  Title = {{National Household Travel Survey: Daily Travel Quick Facts}},
  Year = {2012}}
@article{x,
  author={Adam. Uthor},
  journal={Journal},
  title={Title},
  year={2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\xfnm}[1][]{\ifx!#1!\else\unskip,\space#1\fi}

\begin{document}

Here I am going to use a reference with an institutional author~\cite{BTS2012}.

And \cite{x}

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

It won't work in case the first name starts with `!` (but this shouldn't be a concern).

[image]

---

If you load the `numcompress` package, *don't* modify it. Here's the code you should use, based on your new MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{BTS2012,
  Author= {{Bureau of Transportation Statistics}},
  Howpublished = {\url{http://www.bts.gov/programs/national_household_travel_survey/daily_travel.html}},
  Publisher = {{Department of Transportation}},
  Title = {{National Household Travel Survey: Daily Travel Quick Facts}},
  Year = {2012}}
@article{Shaw1985,
  Author = {Shaw, John J and Gendron, Robert F and Bertsekas, Dimitri P},
  Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems},
  Number = {2},
  Pages = {286--294},
  Title = {{Optimal Scheduling of Large Hydrothermal Power Systems}},
  Volume = {104},
  Year = {1985}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\renewcommand{\xfnm}[1][]{\ifx!#1!\else\unskip\space\removeDot{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}

Here's a reference with an institutional author~\cite{BTS2012}. Here's a journal 
reference~\cite{Shaw1985}. Notice how the periods terminating the authors' first and middle 
initials have been removed, and thus only a final period terminates the list of author 
names, rather than a terminating double period (which would appear as Bertsekas, D.P..).

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]